# How to add example links to documentation pages?

Tags: documentation, workbench

*[Link to Wolfram Community version.](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1051938)*

---

The Details section of documentation pages often contains ">>" links to the examples below.  Is there a quick and easy way to add these links using the Workbench documentation tools when creating my own documentation?  Usually, there is a button for these things in the Documentation Tools palette.  However, I cannot find one for these links.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I received a response to this through [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1051938).

The current Workbench (10.1.822) does not include the tool to create these links.

But the following palette make them:

```
CreatePalette[Button["Create Link", 
 Module[{cell = SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]][[1]], cellid}, 
  cellid = "CellID" /. Developer`CellInformation[cell]; 
  CopyToClipboard[
     Cell[TextData[
       ButtonBox[ToString@cellid, BaseStyle -> "ExampleLink",
       ButtonData -> cellid]]]]]]]
```

Quoting from the W Community response:

> Select the cell you want to link to, click the button in the palette. That copies to the clipboard a link to that cell. Simply paste that link in your notes (yes, it should look like a series of numbers; those numbers are the  CellID of the cell you're linking to). Of course, anyone using this should test it in their own applications to make sure that it works how they want before going nuts with it.

While the link will appear as a number in the source notebooks, it will be translated to `>>` in the final built page.